# When trying to run keras fit(), getting error 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, keras

```
X_train_len = 208 
Y_train_len = 12
y_train=np.ndarray(shape=(num_files,max_y_length),
                     dtype=np.float32)
y_train.fill(1)
##X_train shape is (3,208,224,224,3)
model.fit(x1=[X_train,y_train,X_train_len,Y_train_len], y1=np.ones[208:30], batch_size=1)
```

When I run the fit(), im getting this error. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `y1` value. If you want to create a numpy array of ones, just do:

```py
y1=np.ones((208,30))
```

The one you did, `np.ones[208:30]` tried to access the elements `208 to 30` of np.ones, but, since np.ones is only a function, return an error of `'function' is not subscriptable`.

Comment: Yes ..it worked. But now a new error ``` ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>", "<class 'numpy.ndarray'>"}), <class 'numpy.ndarray'>```

Comment: your `x1` is a list of `int`? try shifting it to an np.array: `x1=np.array([...]), y1=...`

Comment: Your code is too short for me to properly judge what is going on. I noticed a few possible causes of errors though. Your x1 contains values with different shapes, which may cause problems to be raised. Your y1 shape be (208, 12) instead of 30?

Comment: If i were to make sense of your code, I would be doing it like: `model.fit(x1=X_train, y1=y_train, batch_size=1)`